# Как задать массив от -100 до 100? числа должны идти по порядку, без рандома

Tags: pascal

как задать массив от -100 до 100? числа должны идти по порядку, без рандома?

Comment: в цикле от -100 до 100

Answer (score 7):

Паскаль позволяет указывать диапазон индексов для массива, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
A : array [-100..100] of integer
```

И заполнить в простом цикле:

```
For i:=-100 to 100 do 
  a[i] := i;
```

[**Рабочий пример на ideone**](http://ideone.com/RBpIRX)